# Reference request for the integral representation of the Hadamard product of two infinite series

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

Define $F(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} f_{n}x^n$ and $G(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} g_{n}x^n$. Then the Hadamard product of $F$ and $G$ is

$$H(x):=(F*G)(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} f_{n}g_{n}x^n.$$

The author of [Riesz equivalent of Riemann hypothesis and Hadamard product](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351443) claims that

$$H(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} F(\sqrt {x} e^{it})G(\sqrt {x} e^{-it}) \mathrm{d}t.$$

However, no reference/proof of this identity was given. So, does anyone know where I can find the proof/reference of this identity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.C. Titchmarsh, The theory of functions, Oxford University Press

Section 4.6 Hadamard multiplication theorem, p.158

Comment: see also (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526636/hadamard-product-of-two-generating-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Two derivations from operstional calculus:

For

$$A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$$

and

$$\widetilde{A}(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^{a.x}$$

with $(a.)^n = a_n$, the Hadamard product is given by

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n \frac{D_{x=0}^n}{n!} G(x)= \sum_{n\geq 0} a_ng_n x^n $$

with $d/dx= D_x$,

or more concisely,

$$\widetilde{A}(:xD_{x=0}:)G(x)= \exp(a.:xD_{x=0}:)G(x)=G(a.x)= (A*G)(x)$$

with $:xD_x:^n = x^nD_x^n$, by definition, a notational convenience.

The derivatives may be coded as the Cauchy contour integrals

$$g_n = \frac{D^n_{z=0}}{n!}G(z) =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|<\epsilon}  \frac{G(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

where $\epsilon$ is less than the radii of the circles of convergence of the two series.

So, with appropriate changes of variables,

$$H(x)= (F*G)(x)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{n \geq 0} f_n x^n \oint_{|z|<\epsilon}  \frac{G(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz.$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi i}  \oint_{|z|<\epsilon}  \frac{F(\frac{x}{z})G(z)}{z}dz$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi i}  \oint_{|z|<\alpha}  \frac{F(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{z})G(z\sqrt{x})}{z}dz$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_0^{2\pi} F(\sqrt{x}\alpha^{-1}e^{-it})G(\sqrt{x}\alpha e^{it})dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{0}^{2\pi} F(\sqrt{x}e^{-it})G(\sqrt{x}e^{it})dt,$$

assuming both series reps are convergent for $\alpha=1$. The last real integral is convergent for all functions bounded in the segment of integration.

For some discussion of the validity of these formulas, see "[Hadamard grade of power series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0526)" by Allouche and France.

Alternatively, note (cf. [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/is-there-a-formula-similar-to-fxa-ea-fracddxfx-to-express-f-al/126744#126744))

$$\exp(txD_x)f(x)=f(e^t x).$$

Then

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} F(ue^{-it})G(ve^{it})dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-ituD_u}e^{itvD_v} dt F(u)G(v)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-it(uD_u-vD_v)} dt F(u)G(v)$$

$$=\frac{sin[\pi(uD_u-vD_v)]}{\pi(uD_u-vD_v)}F(u)G(v)$$

$$= \sum_{j,k \geq 0} sinc(\pi(j-k)) f_j g_k u^jv^k$$

$$= \sum_{k \geq 0} f_k g_k (uv)^k.$$